# Flask SQL Alchemy,showing Operational Error on Commit Sessions

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The Problem is related to Flask SqlAlchemy where i am not abel to commit my Data into DataBase i have tried many ways but getting Same error ,i have uploaded all my files for that

I am making simple model by following tutorial,these are my all files

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='123456'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////temp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from BlogSite import routes
```

routes.py

```
from flask import render_template,flash,redirect, url_for
from BlogSite import app
from BlogSite.forms import RegistrationForm,SignInForm


login=False

@app.route("/home/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
global login
form=SignInForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash(f'Logged in successfully for ','success')
    login=True
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

return render_template('home.html',login=login,form=form)



@app.route("/Create_Account/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def Create_Acc():
form=RegistrationForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash(f'Account Created successfully for {form.username.data}','success')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

return render_template('Create_account.html',form=form)
```

modals.py

```
from BlogSite import db

class User(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Here in *repr*_ method i also tried the below given code but same error is there

```
return f"User('{self.username}')"
```

run.py

```
from BlogSite import app

if __name__=="__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

My Tree Structure for this is as

[Tree view of my File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qxa.jpg)

list of errors

and also **While i was performing This At that instant Database was not Created on calling of db.create all() function** and also when i just have simply named it as site.db at first at that instant Database was created but on commit error was same only

Errors i am getting as

```
>>> from BlogSite import db
C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds 
significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to 
suppress this warning.
warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
>>> db.create_all()
>>> from BlogSite.modals import User
>>> admin = User(username='admin', email='admin@example.com')
>>> db.session.add(admin)
>>> db.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 681, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2, in commit
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1415, in commit
self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
self._prepare_impl()
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
self.session.flush()
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3233, in flush
self._flush(objects)
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3373, in _flush
transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 198, in raise_
raise exception
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3333, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 453, in execute
rec.execute(self)
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 627, in execute
util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 242, in save_obj
_emit_insert_statements(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1219, in _emit_insert_statements
result = connection._execute_20(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1520, in _execute_20
return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 313, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1389, in _execute_clauseelement
ret = self._execute_context(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 198, in raise_
raise exception
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SPARSH PATHAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 681, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('admin', 'admin@example.com')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
>>>
```

For Trying to solve My Problem,Thank You in Advance

Comment: I don't see any code here that creates the database?

Comment: There is modals.py file

Answer (score 1):

Create a `flask-migrate` object in your application instance:

```py
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
# ...
```

Run your migrations:

```py
(venv)$ flask db init
(venv)$ flask db migrate -m 'user table'
(venv)$ flask db upgrage
```

You should have user table after this

Comment: is there any other way ,then using Flask migrate ?

Comment: Use `SQLAlchemy.create_all()` to generate the tables from your model - see for example: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/